# count amount of numbers in a string

Tags: php

I have a array of random generated strings looking like this:

```
63njpn5u
byrtg1za
ht6wnz39
em1yyrju
2ytoxfxl
n5kaho14
zg92pg4n
gr9e7i01
u3t07ai4
```

I need a php code that will cycle trough these and output the ones back that contain one number. So in the example above I would've gotten back:

```
2ytoxfxl
em1yyrju
byrtg1za
```

I've tried using `preg_match_all` but I cant figure out how to use this with a array.

Comment: Use `array_filter` and call `preg_match()` in the callback function.

Comment: There's no need for `preg_match_all`. Just use the regexp `/^\D*\d\D*$/`

Comment: Use `preg_grep` with your regexp.

Comment: Question, does this contain one number or 2?  ABCD23EFGH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `preg_grep`:

```
print_r(preg_grep('/^\D*\d\D*$/', $your_array));
```

Comment: This worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can count like using string method :

```
$string = "2ytoxfx3l";
echo $int = strlen(intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $string), 10));
```

Group of element:

```
$string = array( "63njpn5u","byrtg1za","ht6wnz39");
foreach($string as $str){
  echo strlen(intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $str), 10));
}
```